# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: root element ([ng-app]) has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am new to the Robot Framework, While running my test case in RIDE, I'm getting this error.

> 20171110 17:00:57.877 :  INFO : Clicking element
>   'css=[ng-click="select()"]'.
>
> 20171110 17:00:58.131 :  FAIL :  WebDriverException: Message: unknown
>   error: root element ([ng-app]) has no injector. this may mean it is
>   not inside ng-app.   (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)    (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.33.506092
>   (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4), platform=Linux
>   4.2.0-42-generic x86_64)

Here is my code,

```
Click Element   css=[ng-click="select()"]           
Sleep   5s
```

Comment: use another locator

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your problem. This should include a full example of your robot code including libraries and the HTML code corresponding to that example.

Answer (score 0):

we have to remove data- from index.html file. Then it will work.

Example: index.html file having

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="adminapp">
    <head>
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <title ng-bind="appData.title"></title>
```

Then we have to remove **data-** from

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="adminapp">
```

Then it will work